# LWUIT 1.4 preverification errors in Eclipse Pulsar + Java Micro Edition SDK 3.0

Tags: eclipse, java-me, lwuit, java-micro-editon-sdk3.0

I am experiencing some preverification error as decsribed in the object.
I googled a lot around before to post this question but found very few responses, most of them very old (2008, 2009) or simply "Pass to NetBeans" ;)

My project includes the LWUIT.jar as local jar in ./lib folder, is targeted to a Java Micro Edition SDK 3.0. The compiler compliance is 1.4, because I heard that LWUIT needs it, 
 and I have not even add the first MIDlet to it. Simply add the jar to the project raises that errors.

Anybody has experienced Pulsar + LWUIT successfully ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [discussion.](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/mobile-embedded/lwuit/got-preverifying-class-error-0?force=804) I'm also getting same issue. Normally Java micro edition sdk 3.0 having some problem with LWUIT. You can try with [sun java wireless toolkit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html).

Comment: Hi, just found it, few seconds ago. "SDK 3.0 is problematic and always has been, it includes its own outdated version of LWUIT which might be interfearing." is the response I was looking for. I just installed WTK 2.5.2 and errors disappeared. Thank you very much :)